# Is $|a-b|\geq |b|-|a|$ always true?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality

[image]

I am trying to understand this part of a proof. My question is why is the inequality only true for sufficiently large $|z|$?

Is $|a-b|\geq |b|-|a|$ only true for sufficiently large $|b|$? because it seems to work for $b=0$.

Also shouldn't $|\gamma^\prime(t)|$ disappear because it is in $L_\gamma$?

Comment: The statement never said it was true *only* for sufficiently large values.  Only that it *is* true for sufficiently large values.  As it is true for *all* values it is true for sufficiently large values.  It emphasis sufficiently large values as that is all they are interested in.  If $|b| < |a|$ then noting that $|a-b| > 0 > |b| -|a|$ is not really useful (it's a no brainer; positives are *always* bigger than negatives!).  But if $|b| > |a| $ then noting that $|a-b| \ge |b| -|a| > 0$.... that *is* useful.

Comment: @fleablood, so the author means that the inequality remains true even if $|z|$ is very large.

Comment: I think the placement of "whenever $z$ is sufficiently large" is confusing: it really applies to line (2.21) to avoid dividing by zero and also to make the denominator arbitrarily large.

Comment: Note:  If $a$ and $b$ are the same sign and $|b| \ge |a|$ then $|a-b|=|\pm(|a|-|b|)|=||a|-|b|| = |b|-|a|$.  If $a$ and $b$ are the same sign and $|b| < |a|$ then $|a-b|> 0 > |b|-|a|$.  And if $a$ and $b$ are different signs then $|a-b|= |\pm(|a|+|b|) = |b| + |a|\ge |b| \ge |b| -|a|$. So, yes, it is *always* true.

Comment: maybe he means "even if" by "whenever".

Comment: I think you *do* have a valid point.  There really was no *need* to say "whenever z is sufficiently large".  I wouldn't say the authors point is that it remains true "even" if $|z|$ is large, but more that "we are concerned with cases where $z$ is sufficiently large, in which case it is true (as it is *always* true)"

Comment: @Cj, Also shouldn't $|\gamma^\prime(t)|$ disappear because it is in $L_\gamma$?

Comment: @gbd $|\gamma(t) - z| \geq |z| - |\gamma(t)|$ is always true. However, the step going from the second inequality to the third inequality **also** requires $|z|$ to be large: at least you also need $|z| > |\gamma(t)|$.

Comment: @gbd $|\gamma'(t)|$ is the speed of the contour $\gamma$ parametrized by $t$, so it's not going to be zero all the time (unless $\gamma(t)$ is constant). Also, I think $L_\gamma$ refers to the length of $\gamma$, not a set.

Comment: The integral of the derivative of gamma is the definition of $L_\gamma$ in the textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always holds. Perhaps that what the author had in mind was this: we always have $\bigl|\gamma(t)-z\bigr|\geqslant\bigl|\bigl|\gamma(t)\bigr|-|z|\bigr|$ and, if $|z|$ is large enough, we also have $\bigl|\bigl|\gamma(t)\bigr|-|z|\bigr|=|z|-\bigl|\gamma(t)\bigr|$.

Comment: I always thought of the inequality $|b-a| \ge |b| - |a|$ as "two no-brainers and one aha".  If $|b| \le |a|$ then $|b-a| \ge 0 \ge |b|-|a|$ (no brainer).  If $b$ and $a$ are opposite signs then $|b-a| = ||b| + |a|| =|b| + |a| \ge |b| \ge |b| -|a|$ (no brainer).  And if $b$ and $a$ are the same sign and $|b| > |a|$ then $|b-a| = |\pm(|b|-|a|)|=||b|-|a|| =|b|-|a|$ (an aha... okay, it's kind of a no-brainer aha but still....)

Comment: Shouldn't $|\gamma^\prime(t)|$ disappear because it is in $L_\gamma$?

Comment: What do you mean? $L_\gamma$ is a number (the length of $\gamma$), not a set.

Comment: In the textbook, we have this proposition https://i.imgur.com/Px3kcdT.png . $\gamma^\prime$ dispears in $L_\gamma$.

Comment: That's because $L_\gamma=\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: @Yes, so the numerator of the first $\sup$ should be $1$ not $\gamma^\prime$.

Comment: No, it should not.

Comment: Then where did the $L_\gamma$ come from?

Comment: I cannot answer in a comment. That textbook seems to be a piece of trash, since even that short extract has several issues.

Comment: My only problem is how we got the first inequality. If you compare with  https://i.imgur.com/Px3kcdT.png you see the $\gamma^\prime$ shouldn't be there. I mean that's how get $L_\gamma$ from $\gamma^\prime$. It is done in previous examples in the textbook too.

Comment: That inequality should be$$\leqslant L_\gamma\sup\left\{\frac1{|\gamma(t)-z|}\,\middle|\,t\in[a,b]\right\}.$$

Comment: You forgot $2\pi$. But that is correct. This is what I meant. $\gamma^\prime$ is a mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133116/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-gbd).